# Python 3 does not recognize nmap module what am I doing wrong here?

Tags: python, pip, nmap

Recently I have been learning python and I have just started a project making a nmap scanning script that will scan a network range for open ports.  My only problem is that I have installed the nmap module but in my code, it says that the module does not have the attribute port scanner when I attempt to run it.  I have looked around quite a bit for a solution and I have seen a lot of different solutions I will list what I have tried here.
First was to install python-nmap that didn't work
Next was to install the module nmap this didn't work either
I also heard you should uninstall nmap and install python-nmap instead this also did not work
Next It was suggested that since I am using python3 I should use pip3 to install python-nmap that didn't work either
Next I tried manually downloading and installing it and putting it in /lib/python3.7/dist-packages this didn't seem to do anything

I did notice that even though the installation did not fail on any of these methods only the manual install made it show up in the dist-packages folder and it still did not work after this.  None of my versions of python have the nmap module inside of them.  Does anyone know anything else that I should try to make this work? I am currently running a Debian 9 based os.  thanks for your help in advance.
this is the error

```
Cannot find reference 'PortScanner' in '__Init__.py'
```

this is my code

```
import nmap
ns = nmap.PortScanner()
```

Comment: show us the code and the actual error message, without your interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to install `nmap`:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

Then install python module:

```
sudo pip3 install -U python-nmap
```

After this you're good to go:

```
>>> import nmap
>>> nm = nmap.PortScanner()
>>> nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')
>>> nm.command_line()
'nmap -oX - -p 22-443 -sV 127.0.0.1'
>>> nm.scaninfo()
{'tcp': {'services': '22-443', 'method': 'connect'}}
>>> nm.all_hosts()
['127.0.0.1']
>>> nm['127.0.0.1'].hostname()
'localhost'
>>> nm['127.0.0.1'].state()
'up'
>>> nm['127.0.0.1'].all_protocols()
['tcp']
>>> nm['127.0.0.1']['tcp'].keys()
[80, 25, 443, 22, 111]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I tried both of these commands it says I have python-nmap and the nmap package installed.  Still does not recognize the port scanner.

Comment: I have added it to my main question as well as the code.

Comment: @Jonlasaga please, do `import nmap` and show us the results of `dir(nmap)` ? And maybe `nmap.__version__` ?

Comment: Ok Im not sure what you mean by import nmap if you mean in the code it is at the very top.  The directory for the nmap module should be 
````
/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
``` and is version 0.6.1 but i cant find it in that directory even though it says its installed there.  The version of nmap installed is 7.80

Comment: @Jonlasaga what i mean, is type `python3`, then when it starts, type `import nmap`, once that done, type `dir(nmap)`.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarifying I have done this in my terminal.  Sorry for the late reply ive been out of town for over a week.  It responded with multiple things i will list them below.
['ET', 'PortScanner', PortScannerAsync', 'PortScannerError', PortScannerHostDict', 'PortScannerYeild', 'process', 'subprocess', sys. etc I did not list them all as I have to post this from mobile but it does seem that I have the portscanner package installed.

Comment: ive noticed that as it says there is no reference to portscanner in init.py though should I add port scanner to the bottom of this document?

Comment: @Jonlasaga if the `dir(nmap)` command lists `PortScanner`, you must be able to use it, like in `nm = nmap.PortScanner()` and do something with it.